# Failing to transition in D3 off new data

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, transition

I can load and display data perfectly once, but any attempt to update seems to fail.

I'm trying to build a map that shows activity.  In my data csv I have latitude and logitude and the hour of activity (0-23).  I am using [this highly useful tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) on updating D3 with new data.  The idea being that I cycle through data by the hour.

I've more-or-less stolen the update function.  While the initial call works perfectly, any repeated calls manage to only recolor the already-present data, rather than remove it and add new data.  This leads me to believe I am not changing the incoming data.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my update call?

```
function update(data, x) {
    // DATA JOIN
    // Join new data to any existing data
    var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data); //, function(d) { return d; });

    // UPDATE
    // Update old elements as needed.
    circles
        .style("fill", "green")
            .transition()
            .duration(750);

    // ENTER
    // Create new elements
    circles.enter().append("circle")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.hr == x; })
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
        })
        .attr("r", 0)
        .style("opacity", 0.2)
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return d.radius/2;
        });


    // EXIT
    // Remove old elements
    circles.exit()
        .style("fill", "red")
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();
}
```

Run from the command line:

```
update(csv_data, 1)
update(csv_data, 5)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with how data joins work in D3?  If not I'd take a look at [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).  Because you most definitely are not changing the incoming data: the line `.data(data)` sets the data for the selection and as per your function calls, `csv_data` is the same in both calls to `update`.

Comment: I could help more (and write up an answer) but I'd need to see what's in `csv_data`.

Comment: I'm using d3.csv to pull in data.  The format is lat, lon, radius, hr

Comment: I get the other 3 but what's `hr`?

Comment: So the data is an array of objects where each object has the 4 properties you've mentioned above?

Comment: That's right.  I just realized I'm sending ALL of the data each time.  So my filters are off.  But if I put the filter in the function call (eg update(csv_date.filter(function (d) {return d.hr == 4;})), the order that I call hours seems to impact which dots to show.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43553/discussion-between-ari-gold-and-scottieb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to change the data by the line

```
filter(function(d) { return d.hr == x; })
```

but that's only [filtering the selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter).

What you want to do is filter the data *before* passing it to your selection which you do with the line

```
.data(data);
```

I suggest using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Ffilter) in the beginning of your update function:

```
function update(data, x) {
    // DATA JOIN
    // Join new data to any existing data

    // filter the data as per x
    data = data.filter(function (d) { return d.hr == x; });

    var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data);

    // rest of function
 }
```

Be sure to remove the line where you filter after the append.

Comment: Closer!  It definitely adds and transitions.
But now it acts weird if I run it in different orders.  Eg running update()  0, 1, 2, 4 results in different dots than running it 4, 2, 1, 0

I also can't call back, so I can't go 0,2,0